# Get Attribute Value with HTML agility

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get class attribute with html agility, but it return with an empty value.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc = hw.Load("https://****.com/" + username);
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
   string hrefValue = link.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);

   // Get the value of the HREF attribute
   if (hrefValue.Contains("following"))
   {                    
       MessageBox.Show( link.GetAttributeValue("class", string.Empty));
   }   

}
```

The html is:

```
<a class="ProfileNav-stat ProfileNav-stat--link u-borderUserColor u-textCenter js-tooltip js-nav u-textUserColor" data-nav="following" href="/SERPRaider/following" data-original-title="2,091 Following">
    <span class="ProfileNav-label" aria-hidden="true">Following</span>
    <span class="u-hiddenVisually">Following</span>
    <span class="ProfileNav-value" data-count="2091" data-is-compact="false">2,091</span>
</a>
```

Comment: please add also sample html code.

Comment: Added HTML snippet code.

Comment: `link.Attributes["href"].Value;` ?

Comment: I am trying to get the class  attribute tried this way and returned with empty don't know why !

Comment: are you sure that html which is returned after get request is the same as you posted in your question. coz i tested it in my project and it worked well, it returned the class name of the first a tag.